# Difference between pandas.dataframe and scipy.stats result

Tags: python, pandas, scipy

I tried to make a result for skew and kurtosis value.
I used famous titanic.age data for this.
First, I used skew and kurtosis function in pandas.dataframe and later I used scipy.stat functions.

Here are the code and result.

```
import numpy
from scipy.stats import skew
from scipy.stats import kurtosis
import pandas

# load data
f = "titanic_survival.csv"
titanic_survival = pandas.read_csv(f)

# retrieve age data
titanic_age = titanic_survival['age'].dropna()

# use dataframe
skew_age_df = titanic_age.skew()
kurtosis_age_df = titanic_age.kurtosis()

#use scipy
skew_age_scipy = skew(titanic_age)
kurtosis_age_scipy = kurtosis(titanic_age)
...

>> result
skew_age_df = 0.40767188649782937
kurtosis_age_df = 0.14694996016357953

skew_age_scipy = 0.4070870379484177
kurtosis_age_scipy = 0.14051780299368888
```

Which one should I use for this calculation? 
Why are the results different?

Comment: Try reading the source code for the methods and I'm sure you're bound to find that the pandas methods are written differently than the scipy methods.

Comment: Before reading the source code, read the docstrings for [`pandas.DataFrame.skew`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.skew.html) and [`scipy.stats.skew`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.skew.html).  In particular, note the comments and options regarding `bias`.

Comment: This has been answered nicely in:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33109107/what-is-the-difference-between-skew-and-kurtosis-functions-in-pandas-vs-scipy/33109272

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between skew and kurtosis functions in pandas vs. scipy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33109107/what-is-the-difference-between-skew-and-kurtosis-functions-in-pandas-vs-scipy)